# Playbook is getting hanged for some time and resuming itself after that

Tags: ansible

When i used WHEN condition for block which contains a lot of tasks the playbook is getting stuck before entering into that block and staying in the hung state for a longtime.

i have added ANSIBLE_SSH_PIPELINING=True in  ansible.cfg, but it's not working.

```
- block:
    - block:
        - name: Interface Status Details
          include: interface_details.yml
          register: result

        - name: Interface Result Global
          set_fact:
            LowerCaseResult: "{{ result.stdout }}
        - debug: var=LowerCaseResult

    - block:
         - name: Calling Dependency Playbook
           include:  one_test.yml
           register: result

         - debug: var=result

      when: "'is up' in LowerCaseResult"

    - block:
         - name: Calling Dependency Playbook
           include:  two_test.yml
           register: cmd_result

         - debug: var= cmd_result
      when: "'is up' not in LowerCaseResult"
  when: true
```

Debug is not printing the playbook is getting stuck for a long time no error message is produced.

Answer (score 0):

(ansible 2.7.9)

*ansible-lint* does not complain about nested *block* (interesting!) See [nested blocks lose conditions on parent blocks #12395](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12395) (ansible locked and limited conversation to collaborators on Apr 25) This might cause problems until resolved.

---

Problems in the code

1) Nothing is registered by *include* use *include_tasks*

```
- name: Interface Status Details                                                 
  include_tasks: interface_details.yml                                           
  register: result
```

2) The closing quotation is missing; If there is no *stdout* in this *result* the task will fail

```
- name: Interface Result Global
  set_fact:
    LowerCaseResult: "{{ result.stdout }}
```

correct, set default to 'is NOT up'

```
 - name: Interface Result Global
   set_fact:
     LowerCaseResult: "{{ result.stdout|default('is NOT up') }}"
```

3) Extra space after *var=*

```
- debug: var= cmd_result
```

correct

```
- debug: var=cmd_result
```

The play below might be working

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - block:
        - block:
            - name: Interface Status Details
              include_tasks: interface_details.yml
              register: result
            - debug: var=result
            - name: Interface Result Global
              set_fact:
                LowerCaseResult: "{{ result.stdout|default('is NOT up') }}"
            - debug: var=LowerCaseResult

        - block:
            - name: Calling Dependency Playbook
              include_tasks:  one_test.yml
              register: result
            - debug: var=result
          when: "'is up' in LowerCaseResult"

        - block:
            - name: Calling Dependency Playbook
              include_tasks:  two_test.yml
              register: cmd_result
            - debug: var=cmd_result
          when: "'is up' not in LowerCaseResult"
      when: true
```